# SQL Как один select вставить в другой select с игнором дубликатов исменой Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Изначальное задание: Скопировать строки из одного документа в другой с игнорированием дубликатов.

1. Скопировать из документа с минимальным номером в документ с
   максимальным номером.
2. Считать, что в заголовке есть по крайней мере одна запись.
3. При добавлении пропускать (не добавлять) строки по товарам, которые
   уже есть.

Вот весь код:

```
CREATE TABLE TOV
(
    KTOV INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NTOV VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    SORT VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE DMZ
(
    DDM DATE NOT NULL,
    NDM INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PR INT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE DMS
(
    KTOV INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TOV(KTOV),
    NDM INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DMZ(NDM),
    KOL INT NOT NULL,
    CENA DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL,
    SORT VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT TOV
VALUES
(101, 'Beer', 'Light'),
(102, 'Beer', 'Dark'),
(103, 'Chips', 'With paprika');
go

INSERT DMZ
VALUES
('01.05.2014', 2, 1),
('01.05.2104', 3, 2),
('02.05.2014', 5, 2);
GO

INSERT DMS
VALUES
(101, 2, 100, 8.00, 'Light'), 
(102, 3, 80, 9.50, 'Dark'), 
(103, 5, 50, 6.50, 'With paprika'),
(101, 2, 1, 10.00, 'Light'), 
(103, 3, 1, 8.50, 'With paprika'), 
(101, 5, 2, 10, 'Light'), 
(102, 3, 1, 11.50, 'Dark'), 
(101, 2, 2, 10.50, 'Light'), 
(103, 5, 1, 8.60, 'With paprika');
GO
```

Есть такой псевдозапрос:

```
INSERT INTO (select * from DMS WHERE NDM = (SELECT MIN(NDM) FROM DMS)) 
FROM (select * from DMS WHERE NDM = (SELECT MAX(NDM) FROM DMS))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Застряла и не могу найти решение. Мне не обязательно готовый ответ нужен, а хотя бы в каком направлении искать

Comment: По суте мне необходимо скопировать с DMS в DMS строки с минимальным NDM, которые не повторяются в максимальном NDM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140987/sql-how-to-insert-one-select-into-another-select-with-the-ignoring-of-duplicate/46141800?noredirect=1#comment79245496_46141800              На stackoverflow английской версии сразу помогли